# Proof that the size of two bases are the same

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to prove that for two bases of an F-vector space $V$ which is finite, $B$ and $B'$, I have $|B| = |B'|$.

My proof of this differed significantly from the given solutions - I was wondering if it was still valid.

Letting $B = \{b_1,b_2,b_3,...,b_n\}$ and $B' = \{b_1',b_2',...,b_m'\}$. Since these are both bases I have $span(B)$ = $span(B')$.

Suppose for a contradiction $|B| \neq |B'|$. WLOG suppose $|B| > |B'|$.

For some $b_i \in B$, $b_m' \notin B/\{b_i\}$. Hence via the Steinitz Exchange Lemma we have $C = B/\{b_i\} \cup\{b_m'\}$.

WLOG let $b_i$ = $b_n$.

$C = \{b_1,b_2,...,b_{n-1},b_m'\}$ is a basis (via S.E.L).
Continuing the process inductively I get:
$$P = \{b_1,b_2,...,b_{n-m+1},b_1',b_2',...,b_m'\}$$ is a basis for $V$. However since $B'$ is a basis for $V$ $b_1 = a_1b_1' + a_2b_2' +...+a_nb_m'$ for some $a_1,a_2,...,a_n \in F$, I get a contradiction hence $|B|\le |B'|$.

Repeating the process with $|B'|>|B|$ then yields that $|B'| = |B|$.

Is my proof valid?

Comment: Yes, this is right as far as I can tell. I always thought using the exchange lemma was the standard way of proving this but perhaps not. You do want to be careful and specify that this is just the finite case, though.

Comment: Are you only considering finite dimensional linear spaces? If yes, you should update your question. And if not, your proof.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net apologies, yes this is for the finite case

Comment: @DanielApsley the proof given in the solutions proves that a linearly independent set's size is $\le$ to a spanning sets size, and then it applies the fact that both bases are linearly independent and spanning to prove it. But contradiction was more natural for me :)